# How to have a slider input change the url hash with its value and vice versa with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am building a pricing calculator with Vue.js.  It is essentially a bunch of html slider inputs that correspond with various questions on each customers needs.  One of the requirements is that you should be able to share the url and it will automatically populate all the pricing information to show the final price breakdown.

I was thinking that each slider could add a url parameter with its value. I was also thinking this could in turn be used by Vue.js watch method to populate the slider input when you enter a url with parameters.  Would it be useful to use the Vue-router package or can this be done relatively simply without the router?

```
    <section class="section">
      <div id="app" class="container">
        <input type="range" min="0" step="1" max="100" v-model="locations">
       <p>Locations: {{ locations }}</p>
     </div>
  </section>
```

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // starting values
    locations: 0
  },
  computed: {
    getLocations: function() {
      var locations = this.locations;
    },
    getLocationsHash: function() {
    //some code here to set url parameters
    }
  }

});
```

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Seems like you should be using the `location.search` rather than hash.

Comment: thanks will take a look at location.search

Comment: Use the router, it will be much easier to handle all the cases.

Comment: for anyone looking to do something similar, I just found [https://github.com/buhrmi/vue-sync](https://github.com/buhrmi/vue-sync) and it works perfectly.